# How Merge multi dataframes Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

```
FinalDf = pd.merge(HRTrainingData,HRDataSet1,HRDataSet2,HRDataSet3, on='EmployeeNumber', how='outer')
```

**TypeError: merge() got multiple values for argument 'on'**

I have only entered one 'on' argument, so I'm not sure what is going on here, but I am unable to merge these data frames. Any advice?

Comment: I believe your problem is because you are trying to merge on more than 2 dataframes at once. You might need to either use `concat` or just do a different `merge` for each dataframe

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn I actually have 15 data frames to merge into one... I tried to start with less because I cant figure out how to do 15.

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn I tried concat but my number of rows don't match my csv file because I cant merge them on a specific column.

Answer (score 3):

You can write like below:

```
pd.merge(df3, pd.merge(df1,df2, on='EmployeeNumber', how='outer'), on='EmployeeNumber',how='outer')
```

Or with `functools.reduce`:

```
import functools

functools.reduce(lambda x,y : pd.merge(x,y, 
                                       on='EmployeeNumber', 
                                       how='outer'), 
                 [df1, df2, df3, df4, ..., df15])
# above code inference like below
# merge(merge(merge(merge(df1, df2), df3), df4), ..., df15)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go. I actually have 15 data frames to merge in total.

Comment: @BrandiAustin, you can use second part for 15 dataframe

Comment: ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: @BrandiAustin, convert all columns `EmployeeNumber` in all dataframes to int or to str then merge them

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use join,

```
df_list=[d.set_index('EmployeeNumber', inplace=True) for d in [df1,df2,d3,d4]]

df_list[0].join(df_list[1:])
```

One of the advantages pd.DataFrame.join over pd.DataFrame.merge, join accepts a list of dataframes.

Comment: KeyError: "None of ['EmployeeNumber'] are in the columns"

Comment: If employeeNumber is already in the index then remove set_index part and just create a list of your dataframes.